# Flash not rendering in IE9

Tags: flash

I've tried every fix I could find, BUT I'm still having issues with flash not showing up on my website in IE9. It's a white hole. It works every other browser. Any suggestions?

```
<div id="flashContent">
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="Untitled-1" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="Untitled-1.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Untitled-1.swf" width="550" height="400">
                <param name="movie" value="Untitled-1.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your Flash file.

Usually it solves crossbrowsers issues.

Here is a very handy code generator: http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/index.html